# ARM template for API Connection to Service Bus using Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azure-managed-identity, azure-logic-app-standard

To create an API Connection to Azure Service Bus using Managed Identity I'm using the following template:

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS",
      "apiVersion": "2018-07-01-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('connections_servicebus_name')]",
      "location": "[parameters('connections_servicebus_location')]",
      "kind": "V1",
      "properties": {
        "alternativeParameterValues": {},
        "displayName": "[parameters('connections_servicebus_displayname')]",
        "api": {
          "name": "[parameters('connections_servicebus_name')]",
          "displayName": "[parameters('connections_servicebus_displayname')]",
          "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('connections_servicebus_location'), '/managedApis/', 'servicebus')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis"
        },
        "customParameterValues": {},
        "parameterValueSet": {
          "name": "managedIdentityAuth",
          "values": {}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

that is actually working except for the fact that the '`NamespaceEndpoint`' information (like: `sb://mySBNS.servicebus.windows.net`) is not provided anywhere and so the field appear empty on Azure portal:

[image]

After adding it manually, the connection and the LogicApp that is using it, start to work.

What is the json field to provide that information??

Comment: Nice shot @old_timer: -2 just for having used 'arm' instead of 'azure-resource-manager'. Thank you for the great contribution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72656531/4167200) for full details:

```json
"parameterValueSet": {
  "name": "managedIdentityAuth",
  "values": {
    "namespaceEndpoint": {
      "value": "sb://<servicebus-namespace-name>.servicebus.windows.net/"
    }
  }
}
```