# Azure api connection bicep deploy status is error

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-managed-identity, azure-bicep, azure-logic-app-standard

I'm trying to deploy a service bus api connection using bicep. This connection should auth using managed identity (in my case, Logic Apps). In my DEV environment the api connection was created from a Logic App, and I'm trying to deploy the same to other environment.

I have tried this:

connections module:

```
param connectionName string
param displayName string
param apiName string
param parameterValues object = {}
param parameterValueSet object = {}

resource connection 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2016-06-01' = {
  name: connectionName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  kind: 'V2'
  properties: {
    api: {
      id: 'subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${resourceGroup().location}/managedApis/${apiName}'
    }
    displayName: displayName
    parameterValues: parameterValues
    parameterValueSet: parameterValueSet
  }
}

output connectionRuntimeUrl string = reference(connection.id, connection.apiVersion, 'full').properties.connectionRuntimeUrl
```

In main.bicep

```
module servicebusApiConnection 'Modules/connection.bicep' = {
  name: serviceBusApiConnectionName
  params: {
    connectionName: serviceBusApiConnectionName
    displayName: serviceBusApiConnectionName
    apiName: 'servicebus'
    parameterValueSet: {
      name: 'managedIdentityAuth'
      values: {
        namespaceEndpoint: {
          'value': 'sb://${serviceBusNamespace.name}.servicebus.windows.net'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the connection says Status "Error" after deploy.

I can see in my service bus api connection in DEV has the option "Logic Apps Managed Identity" for Authentication Type.

[image]

the deployed one look like this. It does not say "This connection can only be used with a managed identity." like the one in DEV.

[image]

Comment: According to the documentaiotn, the api-version is not correct: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity?tabs=standard#multi-authentication-1

Comment: This answer should help as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72656531/4167200

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Api connections(keyvault, servicebus and blob ) using managed identity through bicep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72648651/api-connectionskeyvault-servicebus-and-blob-using-managed-identity-through-b)

Answer (score 0):

you have to deploy the access policy as well (after connections are deployed), i dont have bicep for it but here is an ARM example:

```
    {
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections/accessPolicies",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "name": "[concat('servicebus','/',variables('logicAppName'))]",
  "location": "westeurope",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('logicAppName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "principal": {
      "type": "ActiveDirectory",
      "identity": {
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
        "objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('logicAppName')), '2018-11-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]"
      }
    }
      }
    }
```