# How to paramatize service bus managed identity in 'connections.json' for standard logic apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus, azure-managed-identity, azure-logic-app-standard

I'm attempting to deploy a standard logic app with a service bus connector using a user assigned managed identity but I can't get it to work via terraform and ARM.

It looks connected in portal when I edit the workflow in designer...

[image]

But when I actually trigger the workflow I get the following error...

[image]

`Failed to get oauth token for managed identity in logic app. Response: '{"statusCode":400,"message":"No User Assigned or Delegated Managed Identity found for specified ClientId/ResourceId/PrincipalId.","correlationId":"3b95b432-d690-4703-a571-c5e0d9730c43"}'`

This is my service bus api connection...

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "connections_servicebus_name": {
            "defaultValue": "servicebus",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "uksouth",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "principal_id": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "servicebus_namespace": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "subscriptionId": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "tenant_id": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('connections_servicebus_name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "V2",
            "properties": {
                "api": {
                    "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('location'), '/managedApis/servicebus')]"
                },
                "parameterValueSet": {
                    "name": "managedIdentityAuth",
                    "values": {
                        "namespaceEndpoint": {
                        "value": "[concat('sb://', parameters('servicebus_namespace'), '.servicebus.windows.net/')]"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "displayName": "[parameters('connections_servicebus_name')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections/accessPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('connections_servicebus_name'),'/',parameters('principal_id'))]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
               "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('connections_servicebus_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
               "principal": {
                  "type": "ActiveDirectory",
                  "identity": {
                     "objectId": "[parameters('principal_id')]",
                     "tenantId": "[parameters('tenant_id')]"
                  }
               }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "connectionRuntimeUrl": {
          "type": "String",
          "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('connections_servicebus_name'))).connectionRuntimeUrl]"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the terraform for deploying the above ARM template...

```
data "template_file" "servicebus_connection" {
  template = file("../logic-apps/api-connections/servicebus.json")
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "servicebus_connection" {
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  template_content    = data.template_file.servicebus_connection.template

  parameters_content = jsonencode({
    "principal_id"         = { value = "${data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.identity.principal_id}" }
    "subscriptionId"       = { value = "${var.target-subscription-id}" }
    "servicebus_namespace" = { value = "pip-exec" }
    "tenant_id"            = { value = "${data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.identity.tenant_id}" }
    }
  )

  name            = "connection-${filemd5("../logic-apps/api-connections/servicebus.json")}"
  deployment_mode = "Incremental"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      parameters_content
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the terraform for my standard logic app deployment....

```
resource "azurerm_logic_app_standard" "product_feed_4" {

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment.servicebus_connection,
    azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment.keyvault_connection ]

  name                       = "product-feed-5"
  location                   = "uksouth"
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  enabled                    = true
  storage_account_name       = data.azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_service_plan.slo_app_plan.id
  storage_account_access_key = data.azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.primary_access_key
  https_only                 = true
  version                    = "~4"

  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [ data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.identity.id ]
  }

  app_settings = {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME"     = "node"
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" = "~18"
    "keyVault_VaultUri"            = data.azurerm_key_vault.key-vault.vault_uri
    "ResourceGroup"                = var.resource_group
    "SubscriptionId"               = var.target-subscription-id
    "UserAssignedManagedIdentity"  = data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.identity.name
    "connectionRuntimeUrl"         = jsondecode(azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment.servicebus_connection.output_content).connectionRuntimeUrl.value
  }
}
```

This is my `connections.json`...

```json
{
    "managedApiConnections": {
        "servicebus": {
            "api": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/@appsetting('SubscriptionId')/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/uksouth/managedApis/servicebus"
            },
            "authentication": {
                "identity": "/subscriptions/@appsetting('SubscriptionId')/resourcegroups/@appsetting('ResourceGroup')/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/@appsetting('UserAssignedManagedIdentity')",
                "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
            },
            "connection": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/@appsetting('SubscriptionId')/resourceGroups/@appsetting('ResourceGroup')/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/servicebus"
            },
            "connectionProperties": {
                "authentication": {
                    "audience": "https://servicebus.azure.net",
                    "identity": "/subscriptions/@appsetting('SubscriptionId')/resourcegroups/@appsetting('ResourceGroup')/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/@appsetting('UserAssignedManagedIdentity')",
                    "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
                }
            },
            "connectionRuntimeUrl": "@appsetting('connectionRuntimeUrl')"
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the JSON representation of my workflow which just has 1 service bus action after the trigger...

```json
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Get_messages_from_a_queue_(peek-lock)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "referenceName": "servicebus"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('narvar_events'))}/messages/batch/peek",
                    "queries": {
                        "maxMessageCount": 20,
                        "queueType": "Main",
                        "sessionId": ""
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_HTTP_request_is_received": {
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}
```

Where am I going wrong here?

The API connection shows as 'connected'...

[image]

And the user assigned managed identity has the 'Azure Service Bus Data Owner' role against the service bus...

[image]

Comment: can you chekc this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72656531/4167200? here i was using a different api version to create the connection